# How do I compare doubles using JUnit and Hamcrest?

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

I'm writing a unit test using JUnit and Hamcrest. I have been comparing double values using:

```
assertThat(result, is(0.5));
```

However, I'm now needing to compare calculated values and I don't want to have to compare against the full double value. Instead, I want to compare for closeness.

I've discovered a class called `IsCloseTo` but I'm not sure how to use it in an `assertThat` and I can't find any examples online.

What's the correct syntax to do something like the following?

```
// I can't do this as I need to know what methods/classes whatever I should be using
// isCloseTo doesn't exist.
assertThat(result, isCloseTo(0.5, 0.1));
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should be able to call [`Matchers.closeTo(double, double)`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#closeTo(double,%20double)). With a static import, it looks like:

```
assertThat(result, closeTo(0.5, 0.1));
```

Comment: The full static import for those that are searching for it is: import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.closeTo;

Answer (score 6):

You can make this read better if you use

```
assertThat(actual, is(closeTo(expected, delta)));
```

with

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.closeTo;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
```

Comment: `closeTo` doesn't need `is` wrapper

Comment: That's correct it doesn't _need_ it. It's to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Just worked it out, `is` actually returns an `Is` object, so all I needed to do was:

```
assertThat(result, new IsCloseTo(0.5, 0.1));
```

The answer from nickb is better though.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach would be to use the `closeTo()` matcher (as others have indicated), using `Math.ulp()` to produce the error value. See [What should be the epsilon value when performing double value equal comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3728246) for more discussion. I've opened [Hamcrest Issue #402](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/issues/402) requesting that this capability be added to Hamcrest as a simpler `closeTo()` method that automatically calculates the error value.